# Jupyter notebook on spark standalone cluster cache memory issue

Tags: apache-spark, caching, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

My code was working fine earlier but now it is showing cache memory issue.My program involves DataFrame loading,transformation and processing running on jupyter notebook connected with pyspark-shell.
I am not understanding what is the main issue and how to tackle it.Any Help is highly appreciated.

**My code is:**

```
import time
start = time.time()

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.master('spark://172.16.12.200:7077').appName('new').getOrCreate()
ndf = spark.read.json("Musical_Instruments.json")
pd=ndf.select(ndf['asin'],ndf['overall'],ndf['reviewerID'])


spark.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir("/home/npproject/jupyter_files/checkpoints")

from pyspark.ml.evaluation import RegressionEvaluator
from pyspark.ml.recommendation import ALS
from pyspark.ml.tuning import TrainValidationSplit,ParamGridBuilder
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

indexer = [StringIndexer(inputCol=column, outputCol=column+"_index")       for column in list(set(pd.columns)-set(['overall'])) ]

pipeline = Pipeline(stages=indexer)
transformed = pipeline.fit(pd).transform(pd)
(training,test)=transformed.randomSplit([0.8, 0.2])
   als=ALS(maxIter=5,regParam=0.09,rank=25,userCol="reviewerID_index",itemCol="asin_index",ratingCol="overall",coldStartStrategy="drop",nonnegative=True)
model=als.fit(training)
   evaluator=RegressionEvaluator(metricName="rmse",labelCol="overall",predictionCol="prediction")
predictions=model.transform(test)
rmse=evaluator.evaluate(predictions)
print("RMSE="+str(rmse))
print("Rank: ",model.rank)
print("MaxIter: ",model._java_obj.parent().getMaxIter())
print("RegParam: ",model._java_obj.parent().getRegParam())

user_recs=model.recommendForAllUsers(10).show(20)

end = time.time()
print("execution time",end-start)
```

**Error code is:**

```
Error:
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o40.json.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:    Task 1 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in   stage 0.0 (TID 5, 172.16.12.208, executor 1):   java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/home/npproject/jupyter_files /Musical_Instruments.json does not exist
It is possible the underlying files have been updated. You can   explicitly invalidate the cache in Spark by running 'REFRESH TABLE tableName' command in SQL or by recreating the Dataset/DataFrame involved.
```

Comment: Your traceback shows that _Musical_Instruments.json_ doesn't exist. Have you confirmed this? And what is the cache memory issue that you encounter? Please post the trace for that too.

Comment: Hello Suraj.The file Musical_Instruments.json is existing in the folder.For cache memory issue please refer my error code where it is written that"It is possible the underlying files have been updated. You can   explicitly invalidate the cache in Spark by running 'REFRESH TABLE tableName' command in SQL or by recreating the Dataset/DataFrame involved".I have also tried the suggestion given by error message of recreating dataframe and changing file location but still its not working.

Comment: Is the file present on all the Worker nodes of the cluster? If not, then you have to replicate the folder structure, and place the file on all nodes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I got to know after searching that I have to create replicas of file on all node as I am not using any Distributed file system and running file through Local disk of master node.But is there any way to run the file on spark standalone cluster without creating replicas on node as I don't want to use Hdfs.

Comment: There are multiple options depending on your case and data load.
If your data is small, then you can look at using broadcast variables. For larger data loads, you can use NFS as an alternative to HDFS. 
Or, you can add the files using SparkContext as `sc.addFile(<path>)` and then access it on the workers using `SparkFiles.get(<path>)`. This approach saves you the overhead of having to place files on the workers, but the underlying flow will remain the same.
IMO, using HDFS is the best option as it offers you a rather seamless experience in comparison.